# Julia on Electron Framework

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, julia, ipc

I am going to build an Electron app which requires some math libraries. I have found a great Julia library but I do not know how to use a Julia framework in Electron framework efficiently. Is there any tool like [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) to communicate between Electron and Julia.

Thanks